# is it possible to obtain the intensity of reflected laser light from a DVD or CD-Drive?

Tags: photodiode

I would like to play around with my old CD Drive and stumbled upon the idea of using the CD drive as optical detector for depth or light absorbance. Is is somehow or with some devices possible to obtain the raw data e.g. voltage drop from the detector ?

Comment: what will this do better than an LED and and photodiode? _Reflectance sensors_ are available together in a single package at low cost - some with analog outputs, others with a digital output.

Comment: It would be available in nearly every household.